# Каждое слово в строке с большой буквы (Java)

Tags: java

Код написал,но в консоль выдаются символы при использовании кириллицы.

Символы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Pyatnadcat2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     String s = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println(capitalize(s));
    }


static String capitalize(String s){
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    boolean inWord = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 97 && arr[i] <= 122) {
            if (inWord) {
                continue;
            }
            arr[i] -= 32;
            inWord = true;
        } else {
            inWord = false;
        }
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в *NetBeans* нужно поменять кодировку проекта на utf-8:

Правой кнопкой на проекте - свойства -> картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следующий момент (или замечание?):

Вы вводите в консоль русские буквы, а в методе проверяете латинские строчные:

цифра в html-коде символа - это и есть этот символ в Java, что Вы проверяете (97-122 диапазон) (*кто-нибудь, ради Бога, отредактируйте и напишите правильно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это значит, что Ваш код работает так, что Вы вводите кириллицу - и выводите ту же кириллицу, без манипуляций.

p.s. А вообще, лучше использовать встроенный метод *[toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())* и не забивать себе этим голову ;)

Comment: спасибо) буду знать)

Answer (score 2):

Вместо дремучего кода типа:

```
if (arr[i] >= 97 && arr[i] <= 122)
```

надо использовать нормальные методы типа: `Character.isLowerCase(arr[i])`, а вывих `arr[i] -= 32` лечится методом: `Character.toUpperCase(arr[i])`

А вообще профессиональный подход это использовать внешнюю библиотеку, например [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) где такие вещи уже давно вылизаны и отработаны.

Comment: Спасибо!Я только начал заниматься,потому мне это неизвестно)